# Chrome outline won't disappear in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

https://jsfiddle.net/oyyL5csh/

```
<button class="btn ">
test
</button>

 *:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Bootstrap 4 sets outlines (actually `box-shadow`) for each button variant, (i.e.: `.btn-primary` or `.btn-secondary`). So here's how I achieved it:

```
[class*="btn-"]:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0o33fLk/).